# Generic falsy filter with a typeguard is not narrowing the type correctly

Tags: typescript

Consider this piece of code, that defines a filtering function with a typeguard for filtering out falsy values.

```js
function falsyFilter<T>(
  x: T
): x is Exclude<T, null | undefined | false | 0> { return !!x; }

const filtered = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'].map(x => x === 'a' ? x : 0).filter(falsyFilter);

console.log(filtered);

const consumeString = (s: string) => s+s;

filtered.map(consumeString);
```

What I'd expect is that the last line should produce no type errors. The reality is different. I get:

```
Argument of type '(s: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: 0 | "a", index: number, array: (0 | "a")[]) => string'.
  Types of parameters 's' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```

You can see the example in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAhgGwM4E8BiM1QCmATgDwAqAfABQBQiiAHgFyLm0CUrjiMGiAUUYQ0IACaEKAGkRgQaNIgA+icBOAwwhMcuToMhXQAZKiAN6JihKCGJIAhPcYBuRAF9atCAgxRk+IisdAF5EAG0AchQImQiAIxjEKMT4iIBdADoAWxQAB2oeYNNC4NDkxAB+JkRWIw4MjQISalRMXACSDmdPbzAMODRCDLQ4AHNqM0bA7Tcunp8-XowQLMIAZShiTVHEUOoMVl8tsFGOXdMMAGoMbtopkm1svOollfXN7a6gA).

I'm not sure if I found a bug, or am not understanding what is happening there. Everything works as expected if instead of `0` I use `null` in the ternary inside a `map`.

EDIT:
I think it's connected to how `0` is inferred as `number` in a parameter to `falsyFilter`. So, when this happens the function basically is asked to check if value of type `number` is a `number`, which is always true (but the function returns a `boolean`), so maybe typescript just ignores what is actually returned from the function.

Would be cool if someone could confirm that.

Comment: check this issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20812 you need to be explicit in the `filter`. For instance, doing
`.filter((x): x is 'a' => falsyFilter(x));` works

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Yeah, I get that, but the reason why I created the generic filtering function is to avoid having to specify a type guard every time I filter an array. Since this quesion is not getting much attention I'm going to try to raise an issue on github. I couldn't find an issue describing exactly my problem.

Comment: Actually, the problem is the generic `falsyFilter` isn't capturing the literal type. Try [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgGwM4igXigVwHYBMIBmAlthLlAD5TaYIKVQGJLRUAMDA5JwNwBQfAjgDGwIgHtsjZiBhEEwCACcAPABUoEAB6K8SKEmBKSAcwY0AtgCNlDAN4BfBvGQgAfAAo+UKFoBcUGp8AJQBWlBE+gCiWsIImPjqADSwMm5QdlBKEMCYSlIAhAVaPFAOAsKShozyitnkGADanHCcKZxWbVAtXR2cALoAdBZwYB7haOkTaBg9UAD8vlABbMGDxArKHkyucptKwfx8ldhI4ggQgwjiJtu1ymSHFVXAUCdImBYQAMpGpuhQDxIAKGYzYEzBdDpfQAagMRw2dTIw1GHnenx+f3BhyAA)

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks! Would you care to add an answer to this question and explain more in detail why your solution works, while mine doesn't? It would deserve to be accepted :P